# How to insert square brackets within org-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know that when you want to insert a link you can [[www.google.com][Google]], the square brackets will disappear, but when I want to insert the [[]] and show them like the following code example(I am learning bash and making some notes about it), how do I do??

```
if [[ "$gender" == f* ]]
```

BTW, when I put my cursor in the link descriptor(Google in the link example), but I don't want to open it with my Browser, how can I know the original url(www.google.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use org-babel source blocks for scripts.
That looks like:

```
#+begin_src shell-script
if [[ "$gender" == f* ]]
#+end_src
```

Pressing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> inside such a block will execute it. The results are shown underneath. Pressing <kbd>C-c '</kbd> gives you another buffer for editing the source block (in its own major mode).

You find a short description at: <kbd>C-h i g (org) Literal examples</kbd>.

BTW, the menu items <kbd>Org → Hyperlinks → Descriptive Links</kbd> and <kbd>Org → Hyperlinks → Literal Links</kbd> let you switch between descriptive and literal links.

Comment: The command corresponding to the menu items mentioned here is `org-toggle-link-display`. @CodyChan If you find that you need to switch between descriptive and literal links a lot, it makes sense to set up a key binding for it: `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x t") 'org-toggle-link-display)`